# How to get multiple elements of text from one div with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup, together with Flask, to scrape and show elements on a page. However, I'm having some trouble understanding what I need to do to get multiple items from a single div, and how to write it in a for loop, to show up properly in a HTML file. I'll explain it much better with code.

This is the HTML layout I'm attempting to scrape:

```
<div class="card card-job">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title"><a class="stretched-link js-view-job" href="#">Associate Account Manager
                            [MedTech]</a></h2>
                    <div class="card-job-actions js-job" data-id="2306150237w"
                        data-jobtitle="Associate Account Manager [MedTech]">
                        <button class="btn-add-job " aria-label="Save Associate Account Manager [MedTech]" title="Save">
                            <svg class="icon-sprite">
                                <use xlink:href="/images/sprite.svg"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="sr-only">Save</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn-remove-job d-none" aria-label="Remove Associate Account Manager [MedTech]"
                            hidden="" title="Remove">
                            <svg class="icon-sprite">
                                <use xlink:href="/images/sprite.svg"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="sr-only">Saved</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-inline job-meta">
                        <li class="list-inline-item">Sales - Selling MDD</li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item">Mongkok, China</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I need two things from it:

1. The card title text, inside h2, under the `card-title` class, and
2. The description text, inside the list, under the `job-meta` class.

I can get them individually, without any issues. For example, for card title:

```
job_title = job.find_all("h2", {"class": "card-title"})
jobs = [i.get_text() for i in jobs_title]

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', jobs=jobs)
```

And then I write a for loop inside my HTML file, that gets the list of job titles:

```
<div class="jobs">
    {% for job in jobs %}
    <h3>{{ job }}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

However, if I take this approach and scrape the job description the same way, I have no way of adding it to the loop inside the HTML, so that it shows in proper order:

1. Job Title 1, Job Description 1,
2. Job Title 2, Job Description 2

Which leads me to believe I need a for loop inside my py file, as well. So this was the best I could come up with, but it's giving me a TypeError: 'ResultSet' object is not callable.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
jobs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "card-job"})
for job, desc in jobs(soup.find_all("h2", {"class": "card-title"}), 
                      soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "job-meta"})):
    print(job, desc)
```

What did I do wrong here? And how do I pass it into def home, and use it inside the HTML?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you a hint concerning selection strategy - Try to get each card and scrape all related information in one go:

```
data = []
for e in soup.select('.card'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.h2.text,
        'descr':e.ul.get_text('\n',strip=True)
    })
```

Now you should be able to iterate `list` of `dicts` to glue everything together.